# "Email already in use" Apple ID error message. How can I set it up?

Tags: email, apple-id, authentication

A little over month ago I received an email from the Russian Apple website, asking me to confirm my email to complete the registration of my Apple ID. I am thinking someone possibly used my email by mistake. I did not click the authentication link. The message stated that if it wasn't me who registered, I shouldn't worry.

However, now I am trying to create an Apple ID but I get the error message:

> "Email already in use"

I have never registered for an Apple ID with my email address. Resetting the password through email authentication does not send me any email.

What can I do?

Comment: Mr Russian, i have same exact issue. i just got my first iphone and set up everything except my apple id. i have only 1 email and it says that my email is already in use with another apple id

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking someone possibly used my email by mistake. I did not
>   click the authentication link. The message stated that if it wasn't me
>   who registered, I shouldn't worry.

I highly doubt someone else could register with your email, since you stated right afterward ***you*** yourself had registered with it.

Try clicking this link then fill out the information required:

```
https://iforgot.apple.com/iForgot/iForgot.html
```

[image]

Comment: i did not register with it, i said i tried registering just now. that attempt was from over a month ago. and like i said, when i try to reset the password, there are 2 options - by mail and by answering security questions. the email option doesn't work (i do not receive any mail), and the first sec question is about the daste of birth - which is not mine. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would contact Apple about this via their [Apple ID Support page](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/).

Comment: i spent a while on this page trying to figure out what can i do... looks like they don't provide support in my country :\ thanks.

Comment: @daniel Really? Wow, that sucks. Sorry to hear that. Do you have an Apple Store you could visit?

Comment: yeah, some local representative. i might go there and ask them. it's just weird that there's no sort of worldwide general email/chat/web form for that purpose.